# How do you configure Zend Framework 1.11.11 and netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: netbeans, zend-framework

I tried every possible solution that I found on Google but netbeans keeps telling me "Zend Project not created!" type of error.

- Added paths in environment variables of windows,
- Copied "zf.bat, zf.sh,zf.php" to php directory of xampp (C:\Program
  Files\xampp\php),
- configured tools->option->php->general and tools->options->php->zend,

Sometimes it says cannot open ~dp0/zf.php file, sometime it says something is not accessible on line nu. 319 of zf.php.

Is there anyone, who can guide me in configuring zend framework 1.11.11 on netbeans 7.0.1 from scratch.

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Download latest netbeans such as nightly builds. It by default supports those BaSH or BATCH files.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

even I had the same problem, what we were missing was, inside php.ini, we need to include the library of zend framework, I am showing you the snippet of my php.ini...

; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;E:\xampp\php\PEAR;**E:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework\library;**"

As you can see the bold text is the path of zend library, just add it in the same way and
that's it... and the error gets fixed. Hope it works, just try and let me know.

Regards